# How to Switch Some Basic Keys in Windows (Windows VirtualBox Guest on OSX Host)

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

I am going crazy switching between Windows XP in a VirtualBox and the host (OSX), mostly due to the use of control-c, control-v, control-x and that they are different  between the two OSes.

Is there any way to get my Windows machine to use different shortcuts OS-wide?

**Edit:** I really need a way to override Windows-C Windows-X Windows-V Windows-Z and Windows-Tab (copy, cut, paste, undo and switch-apps) for the solution to work for me.

**Edit:** Thanks for John T.'s help, I've got my autokey stuff working. I posted my final code for Windows guests on OSX [here](http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2010/01/windows-keys-annoying-as-guest-os-on.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, check out [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com). You can choose to have the hotkeys work on a per-application basis or system wide.

example:

```
^!n::Run C:\Windows
```

This will allow you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to open an explorer window to `C:\Windows`.

The [hotkeys tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) is a great start for making your own custom hotkeys.

Comment: Man I'm glad I asked. Are you the Jon Skeet of superuser?

Comment: You can make WinXP machine interpret some other keys as 'Copy', 'Paste' and other actions, but you cannot stop it from interpreting Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V the same way.  
@John: how do you highlight hotkeys that way? I read the whole help, but didn't found anything regarding.

Comment: thanks whitequark. that might be fine. @John T, I edited the question to reflect what I need. Can Autohotkey do it?

Comment: AHK can do ^c ^v just as easily. And the keyboard keys are in <kbd> tags.

Comment: @Yar you can use `#c::Send ^c` to make the windows key and c send Ctrl-C, if that's what you're after? Similar with `#v::Send ^v` ...

Comment: John, I think so, I just need to "interrupt" the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, which I think should be possible. I'll have to get into this shortly and then mark you as best answer. Thanks again...

Comment: @Yar you're most welcome. Feel free to email me with any further discussion as I'm leaving for work now. I'll get back to you as soon as possible if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks John, I'm going to have to put in a tiny bit of work to get hotkeys to do what I want, but I think I have all the pieces I need.

Comment: John T I'm marking this as best answer, and I put my script in the question. You rock, thanks again!

Comment: @Yar, good timing I just got in :) To map win+tab you can use `#tab::send ...` (replace the dots accordingly).

Comment: Thanks John, we just crossed messages, everything worked out nicely, had to work with `LWin & Tab::AltTab` because it maps to AltTab.

Comment: And blogged, too http://linkee.com/5Ir

Answer (score 7):

Just for the Super User archives, something I found [at some blog](http://yar2050.com/2010/01/windows-keys-annoying-as-guest-os-on.html). ;-)

> 1. Change your Host key on VirtualBox to be the RIGHT command key
> 2. Download [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
> 3. Put this script in as the startup script
>
> ```
>  #SingleInstance force
>  #r::Send ^r ;reload
>  #z::Send ^z ; undo
>  #y::Send ^y ; redo
>  #f::Send ^f ; find inside apps
>  #c::Send ^c ; copy
>  #x::Send ^x ; cut
>  #v::Send ^v ; paste
>  #t::Send ^t ; new tab, Firefox
>  #s::Send ^s ; save inside apps
>  LWin & Tab::AltTab ; the motherlode, alt-tab!
> ```
>
> and you're up and running!

Comment: I love that blog! I'm like the only reader! Thanks Arjan...

Answer (score 5):

First change the Host Key to Right Command key...

And then change all usages of Windows key to Control Key, in your AHK script.

```
LWin::LCtrl
LCtrl::LWin
```

Now the keys are remapped for all shortcuts!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to remap the keys.  I found [this HowToGeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/219156/how-to-remap-your-windows-cutcopypaste-to-os-x-like-controls-and-vice-versa/) helpful for walking through the steps on OS X and Windows.