# Change Windows-E Target

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering how we can change the `Win-E` key combination to another target besides the default `C:\`.

I've tried changing the shortcut in `Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> Windows Explorer` to `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "C:\My Folder\"`, in case `Win-E` references this shortcut, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/102249/.  Basically (Superuser's favorite answer) Autohotkey.  http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is set up an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

(I am no expert here, but this should work)

```
#e::Run COMMAND
```

For example

```
#e::Run calc
```

will start calculator when the <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> are pressed.

EDIT-

For your specific case, Copy and paste this:

```
#e::RUN Explorer.exe "c:\MY Folder\"
```

and save it as anything with a `.ahk` file extension. Next, install AutoHotKey and then run the file. It should intercept <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and launch what you want.